# Call subclass method from superclass - Design Pattern

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I am stucked here, because I am worried whether it is best practice to call a class method of a child class from a parent class?

```
module Zoo

  class Animals
    class << self
      def update
        if self.whatever == ... # Calls method 'whatever' from Tiger class
          # do sth.
        end    
      end
    end
  end

  class Tiger < Animals      
    def update
      super
    end
    class << self
      def whatever
        "whatever from tiger class"
      end
    end
  end
end

Zoo::Tiger.update
```

It works, but I would appreciate any better solution to this problem. I want to follow best practice solutions as much as possible unlike some custom hack.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `update` method in `Tiger` is never called. `Tiger`'s singleton class inherits the method defined in `Animals`' singleton class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Animals
  def self.update
    puts "self = #{self} in Animals::update"
    if whatever == "Happy Days"
      puts "The Fonz rules"
    end    
  end
end

class Tiger < Animals      
  def self.whatever
    "Happy Days"
  end
end

Tiger.update
  # self = Tiger in Animals::update
  # The Fonz rules
```

Before discussing this, a few notes:

- I've removed the module `Zoo` and the instance method `Tiger#update` as they are not relevant to the question.
- I've removed `self.` from `self.whatever`, as it is not needed (`self` is assumed if there is no explicit receiver).
- I've defined the class methods in the more conventional way (but there is nothing wrong with the way the OP defines them).
- `update` is only to be invoked from subclasses, as `Animal.update` would raise a "there's no method or local variable 'whatever'" exception.

The important point here is that `Tiger.update` invokes the method `Animal::update`, *just as though `update` had been defined in `Tiger`*,  rather than having been inherited from `Animal`. That's why:

```
Tiger.methods.include?(:update) #=> true
```

Therefore, "call a class method of a child class from a parent class" is not correct; `Tiger::whatever` is being called from the child class. Nothing is being called from the parent class because `self` never equals `Animals` when `Tiger::update` is invoked. This is not just semantics.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very normal pattern. You can then implement `whatever` differently in each child class without having to reimplement `update` in each of them. All I would add is:

```
def self.whatever
  raise NotImplementedError, 'Class must implement whatever' # or some useful message
end
```

to the `Animal` class. That way, if you call `ChildClass.update` from a child class that doesn't implement `whatever`, you get a useful error.

Comment: In addtion to adding an exception-raising class method `whatever` to `Animals`, it might be useful to make the first line of `Animals::update` the following: `raise NotImplementedError, "update is only to be called from subclasses" if self == Animals`. Perhaps make your error message `"class #{self} must implement..."`.